# Installing ColdFusion 11 on Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8.0

Tags: windows, iis, coldfusion

I've done this many times in the past, but this is new, and I think CF11 is the problem.  Not sure.

Fresh Windows Server 2012.. installed CF11.  Selected "Configure All IIS Websites" during install.  There's only two sites configured in IIS -- Default, and one other, which has its own name (test.mydomain.com) configured in the hosts file and in DNS.  In its webroot is a single index.cfm file, and a subdirectory thereof, is an actual ColdFusion web app.

When I browse to the webroot, I get a standard Microsoft IIS page, rather than the index.cfm file.  If I browse to the subdirectory, I get 404.

- I've set index.cfm as the default document.
- The path specified to the webroot is correct.

If I run the wsproxyconfig.exe file, it shows nothing is configured.  I click Add, select IIS.  In the drop-down where you configure a specific site, it says None and is not selectable.  If I try to add, I get the error, "Unable to configure WebSocket Proxy Enable the required WebSocket Protocol option in IIS."  I've looked all over IIS and can't find where this setting might be.

What's interesting is I can get the cfadmin page to load and function just fine (127.0.0.1/cfide/administrator)... there are no port numbers in that URL so it must be passing through IIS.  So I'm not really sure what the problem is.  Is it the connector?  Is it something else?  I'm stumped.

Comment: This will be an issue with the bindings for your site in IIS. The coldfusion admin is available through each virtual site, which is why you can access it, but the reason you are getting the default IIS page is because which ever url you are using is not bound correct in IIS. What bindings do you have for "test.mydomain.com" and what have you configured for the HOST file and DNS? Sidenote - wsproxyconfig is used for Websockets, which unless you need can be ignored for now.

Comment: I agree with haxtbh. You could further verify that this is an IIS, HOST file or DNS issue by binding the website to an alternative port like 73 and check if you can accesss the site on the server by visiting http://127.0.0.1:73. If so coldfusion is correctly installed for this website. BTW i think you meant to run wsconfig.exe in stead of wsproxyconfig.exe

Comment: Thanks guys. You know what fixed it? In the bindings I had specified the server's IP instead of just saying "ALL IPs."  Never had that happen before.  Weird.  But talk about a problem with a thoroughly weird error, exacerbated by me running the wrong damn "ws" config app!!  Augh.